# Dropped "when" in "Remember a time you ate an apple"

Tags: grammar, relative-adverbs

I am reading a sentence that seems weird to me:

> Remember a time you ate an apple.

In this sentence it seems to be missing a "when".

> Remember a time **when** you ate apple.

Can you tell me how the first one is correct?

Comment: In informal speech and writing, we can drop when, where, which, etc. The place you waited for a bus, the time you saw a tiger, the book you read last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there’s a verb immediately after the relative pronoun, it’s a subject, and you can’t omit the relative pronoun. If there’s no verb, you can omit the relative pronoun when, where, which, that, etc. The place [where] you waited for a bus, the time [when] you saw a tiger, the book [which/that] you read last week.

[Omitting relative pronouns](https://englishharmony.com/omitting-relative-pronouns/)